# How to close HTTP connection with okhttp?

Tags: java, okhttp

How one is supposed to tell OkHttp that a connection to an HTTP server should be closed after a request has finished?

Suppose I use the following code to make a request to google.com

```
OkHttpClient cl = new OkHttpClient();
Request req = new Request.Builder()
              .url("http://www.google.com")
              .header("Connection", "close")
              .get()
              .build();
Response res = cl.newCall(req).execute();
System.out.println("Response message: " + res.message());
System.out.println("Reponse body: " + res.body().string());
```

by using "Connection: close" I'm able to get the remote server to send a FIN (if I don't, the remote server just hangs awaiting for new requests). Still, on the client side no FIN is produced, and the connection stays half opened apparently for an indefinitive amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, it's a regression in OkHttp 2.0.0-RC1. [Fix](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/897) is out for review.

Comment: I see. Anyway, is setting "Connection: close" supposed to be the right way to close the connection after the request has completed?